# haskell optimized fill of max value

Tags: haskell, recursion, traversal

Started building some small real world stuff in Haskell for getting some routine. Need piece of code that takes a value-A (`max`) and a list of values `(x:xs)` that will return a list of values of which the sum equals or is lower than value-A. What I have now below, but this keeps fitting numbers until full. It will not return the most optimal sequence.

```
fill :: Int -> [Int] -> Int 
fill max (x:xs) = if x < max then fill (max - x) xs else fill max xs
fill max [] = max
```

I think I would need to write a function that takes the first value of the list, traverses the rest of the list for the most optimal addition, add that to another list and keep doing that until the smallest remainder or a match with `max`. Guess might be simple for you but proven a tough nut to crack for me.

Edit: if I sort the value list first, it's a little simpler it seems, since I can discard values that blow up `max`

Comment: This looks similar to the *subset sum* problem (and the bin packing problem). You need to use *dynamic programming* for this.

Comment: @Willem: can you elaborate on that to get me on track? Searched for a similar problem, but could not really find something equal. Will look for 'subset sum' problem then.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: A naive approach would be to simply `filter` the result of applying `subsequences` to the input list in order to find the subsequences which sum to the specified value. A more optimal approach requires dynamic programming, as @WillemVanOnsem mentioned.

Comment: @Willem, Asad: checked the Wiki and it looks similar. It also looked like a deceptively simple problem to me, but seems a lot more complicated...

Comment: @Madderote well, it _is_ simple to do this with brute-force, but the performance of this is very bad. That might still be ok for you, if you're only dealing with very small lists.

Comment: @Madderote It may look simple at first, but it turns out that checking if `max` can be reached is an NP complete problem (subset sum). So, we had theoretical computer scientists around the world trying to find efficient solutions to this (& related problems) for 50 years, and a still unclaimed 1M$ prize for an efficient solution. Definitely not simple at all. For "small" lists, though, coding a slow brute force algorithm is feasible.

Comment: Thanks @Chi for the added context. Willem also put me in that direction. Found a brute-force way to do it but it is not elegant and way to slow for the dataset I need it for, so I'' side-track it and try to figure something more elegant. It is good to know that for once it isn't me that can't figure out a proper solution :)